# How to redirect QEMU -serial output to both a file and the terminal or a port?

Tags: qemu

I would like to be able to both interact with the system via the command line, but also get the output to a file at the same time.

If I do:

```
qemu-sysem-x86_64 -serial stdio |& tee file
```

then it mostly works, but I would like to avoid any Bash operations and let QEMU do the heavy lifting for me. For example, I'm using Python, and it is not so simple to implement a reliable `tee` there.

If I do:

```
qemu-sysem-x86_64 -serial file:myfile
```

It redirects to the file and I can't give any input.

Is there a way to "combine" both `file:` and `stdio` to a single `-serial`?

Multiple `-serial` entries just create multiple serial ports instead of modifying a single one.

I'm also interested if it works with telnet as in:

```
-serial tcp::1234,server,nowait
```

http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2018-11/msg00011.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Recently, I ran into the exactly same problem and found a solution:

According to [QEMU 3.1.0 documentation](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#Character-device-options), you can use a `chardev` with options `stdio` and `logfile` and redirect your `serial` into it.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -chardev stdio,id=char0,logfile=serial.log,signal=off \
  -serial chardev:char0
```

Moreover, if you use `mux=on` option within `chardev`, you can redirect a monitor (`mon`), another `serial` or other interfaces supporting `chardev` backend into it simultaneously:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -chardev stdio,id=char0,mux=on,logfile=serial.log,signal=off \
  -serial chardev:char0 -mon chardev=char0
```

See the example in the doc. link above.

Comment: Awesome!!! Can you also provide the full CLI to do the `mon` setup (hopefully something analogous to `-serial mon:stdio` but with logging)? I also wanted that actually, but forgot to mention in question, and my initial attempts failed.

Comment: In particular, I'd like Ctrl+C to go to guest instead of kill QEMU. Ideally mon output should not go to log file.

Comment: The signals like Ctrl+C can be enabled or disabled with `signal=on|off` option within `chardev`. I'll provide the `mon` example as edit.

Comment: Perfect! `signal=off` does what I wanted.

Comment: `signal=off` seems to be the preferred way, will add it as edit.